# Angular Universal - Render once main.js loads

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am running an Angular Universal project. The problem I'm running into is that my page starts to render before the main bundle is completely loaded resulting in an incorrect render.

When main.js loads the site renders properly. This causes ugly flickering when the site is loaded on a slow network connection.

Is there anything I can do to delay rendering until main.js has finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra option for RouterModule **InitialNavigation**, and set it to 'enabled'.

When set to Enabled, the initial navigation starts before the root component is created. The bootstrap is blocked until the initial navigation is complete. This value is required for server-side rendering to work.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
        initialNavigation: 'enabled'     
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Reference: https://angular.io/api/router/InitialNavigation

Comment: This does not change anything. The site still tries to render before the bundle is loaded.

Comment: The idea of using universal is to serve a prerendered HTML content of the page... if component visibility depending on main.js this might cause this flicker. if you can share screenshots of the unusual behavior you are facing

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah, the rendered component depends on a library within main.js.

This is what it looks like before it loads: https://ibb.co/NTh4JPZ
This is what it is supposed to look like: https://ibb.co/XFtNJLb

It fixes once main.js and ng-slider within main.js loads. This can be seen at https://blika.is

Comment: so I guess your problem is a branding issue with your HTML and styles and nothing related to Universal... 
Try to add styles related to the slider in the component style file and not in the global styles.scss  and make sure that the slider renders correctly before the slider plugin initialize.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only bootstrap the client app when the dom rendering is completed.

**main.ts**

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had it like this before, but it did not work. I ended up hiding the slider until ngAfterViewChecked is called. Not an optimal solution, but it works.